# Adding to my arraylist causes ConcurrentModificationException even with iterator

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist

Before adding works fine with the normal for each loop, but removing isn't so I used an iterator. Now every 3rd item I add to my arrayList gives me a `ConcurrentModificationException`. What seems to be the problem?

`private ArrayList<Marker> mMarkers` which is instantiated in `onCreate`

Here I have a list view on my `onCreateView`

```
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final Events event = mEventsParseQueryAdapter.getItem(position);

            GoogleMap googleMap = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();

            if (mMarkers.isEmpty()) {
                mMarkers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(getLatLngFromGeoPoint(event.getLocation()))));
            } else {
                Iterator<Marker> markerIterator = mMarkers.iterator();

                //noinspection WhileLoopReplaceableByForEach
                while (markerIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Marker marker = markerIterator.next();
                    if (marker.getPosition().equals(getLatLngFromGeoPoint(event.getLocation()))) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        mMarkers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(getLatLngFromGeoPoint(event.getLocation()))));
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and here's my marker on click listener which pops a dialog and have an option to remove the marker

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(), CONSTANT.ZOOM_LEVEL));

            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.checkout, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mMarkers.remove(marker);
                    marker.remove();
                }
            }).setPositiveButton(R.string.frames, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            dialog.create().show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mMarkers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
```

is called inside your iteration loop (`while (markerIterator.hasNext()))`, so you are adding element at the time of traversing the collection which gives you the error.

Actually you probably wanted the :

```
           } else {
                mMarkers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(getLatLngFromGeoPoint(event.getLocation()))));
            }
```

branch not inside the loop but rahter outside the whole while loop (when no existing marker was found a new one is created and added.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify a list while iterating over it, no matter whether you use for-each or an iterator. Read more on the exception page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing/adding or reading/writing on the list concurrently using a fail-fast iterator(markerIterator in your casE). If the iterator will detect such behavior in the code it will throw this exception.

> it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it

Hence your read/write operations should be disassociated, time vise.